# How can I update a vector inside a while loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, while-loop

I'm trying to write a simulation in python for a Michaelis-Menten biochemical system of reactions as follows:

E + S --> ES == 1E + 1S + 0ES + 0P --> 0E + 0S + 1ES + 0P

ES --> E + S == 0E + 0S + 1ES + 0P --> 1E + 1S + 0ES + 0P

ES --> E + P == 0E + 0S + 1ES + 0P --> 1E + 0S + 0ES + 1P

I've used the following arrays to detail the information of the system

```
popul_num = np.array([200, 100, 0, 0]) # Molecule numbers 
LHS = np.array([[1,1,0,0], [0,0,1,0], [0,0,1,0]]) # ratio of reactants in each reaction 
RHS = np.matrix([[0,0,1,0], [1,1,0,0], [1,0,0,1]]) # ratio of products in each reaction
stoch_rate = np.array([0.0016, 0.0001, 0.1]) # rate of reactions 
state_change_array = np.asarray(RHS - LHS) # state change after a reaction occurs 

tmax = 20.0 # maximum time of simulation 
tao = 0.0 # start time of simulation
```

I have then written the following function that calculates the probability of a reaction firing:

```
def propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate):
propensity = np.zeros(len(LHS))
for row in range(len(LHS)):
        a = stoch_rate[row]     
        for i in range(len(popul_num)):
            if (popul_num[i] >= LHS[row, i]):       
                binom_rxn = binom(popul_num[i], LHS[row, i])
                a = a*binom_rxn
            else:
                a = 0
                break
        propensity[row] = a     
return propensity
```

The method I'm trying to use is the time discretisation gillespie algorithm, where the probability of a reaction firing within a certain specified time interval is calculated. I've written the following while loop to do this:

```
delta_t = 1.3 # specified time interval 
popul_num_all = [popul_num]
propensity = np.zeros(len(LHS))

while tao < tmax:
    propensity = propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate)        
    a0 = (sum(propensity))
    if a0 == 0.0:
        break
    lam = (propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate)*delta_t)
    rxn_vector = np.random.poisson(lam)  <-- PROBLEM HERE: Need to update the rxn_vector after each iteration, with new probabilities of a given reaction occurring     
    print("reaction vector:\n", rxn_vector) 
    # needs updating on every iteration! 
    if tao + delta_t > tmax:
        break
    tao += delta_t
    for row in range(len(state_change_array)):
        for j in range(len(rxn_vector)):
            popul_num = popul_num + state_change_array[row]*rxn_vector[j] 
    popul_num_all.append(popul_num)
```

My problem is in the while, each iteration is meant to update the propensity function (probability a reaction fires) and then this is meant to be used to update the rxn_vector (probability a reaction fires in the given time interval delta_t) but at the moment the rxn_vector isn't being dated.

I then have the following code to plot the output:

```
popul_num_all = np.array(popul_num_all)
for i, label in enumerate(['Enzyme', 'Substrate', 'Enzyme-Substrate complex', 'Product']):
    plt.plot(popul_num_all[:, i], label=label)
    plt.legend()
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I've got numpy, Scipy and matplotlib imported

Cheers

Comment: What is the `binom_rxn = binom(popul_num[i], LHS[row, i])` `binom` function? I'm guessing you import scipy.stats.binom?

Comment: Yes, numpy, scipy and matplotlib are all imported, so I can use binomial, poisson distributions and discrete random variables